# Bad Gateway error using rtime as_search in R

Tags: r

I am using *nytimes* API in R with *rtimes* package and using *as_search* function to search articles.
I am using following code to make 10000 calls by giving page argument in *as_search*.

```
library("rtimes")
library('dplyr')

Sys.setenv(NYTIMES_AS_KEY = "apikey")

df <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:1000){
  x <- as_search(q = "trump", page = i)
  df <- bind_rows(df, x$data)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Fetching few articles results in the following error:

> Error: Gateway Timeout (HTTP 504)`

Can any one tell me why it is occurring?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the sleep time to see if it works with much longer sleep intervals?

Comment: Fixed typo and grammar. A bit of formatting too.

Comment: i have tried with Sys.sleep(2) but the error remains the same